# Gracefully terminating a virtual sequence by itself

Tags: sequence, system-verilog, uvm

I am looking for a way to gracefully end the task:body of a virtual sequence upon hitting a certain condition inside the same vseq body.
ex:

```
task my_vseq::body();
    some logic;
    if (condition met)
        end of my_vseq
    some other logic;
endtask : body
```

for the part where i'm hoping to end my_vseq i've tried:

```
endtask : body -- giving syntax error as 2 endtask are defined. 
$finish -- giving inconclusive status for uvm test.
```

the requirement here is to the have a way of terminating the my_vseq in middle and not have uvm_fatal or other negative status

Comment: done the edits for visibility

Answer (score 3):

Use the `return` statement. See the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595), section *13.3 tasks*:

> A task exits when the `endtask` is reached. The `return` statement can be used to exit the task before the endtask keyword